# Is it possible to upgrade/move to Jolicloud from Ubuntu Netbook Remix?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-netbook-remix, jolicloud

I have a Dell Mini 9 running Ubuntu Netbook Remix. I would like to switch to [Jolicloud](http://jolicloud.com) (which is based on UNR.) I would like to know if it's possible to easily upgrade/move from UNR to Jolicloud, or if I must do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

edit /etc/apt/sources.list and add the following:

```
deb http://apt.jolicloud.org robby main directory jolicloud
deb-src http://apt.jolicloud.org robby main directory jolicloud
```

run these commands.

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude install -R jolicloud-poulsbo
sudo aptitude install -R linux-image-jolicloud linux-image-jolicloud-atom
sudo /etc/jolicloud-netbook-config.d/poulsbo.sh
```